# Set template for custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, page-attributes

Is there a way to add the template selection dropdown to the custom post type? Perhaps under Page Attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far it seems there is no native way to do it in WordPress, correct me if I am wrong. If you are okay with using plugins there is [Custom Post Template](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-template/) that you could try.

Comment: Note that the plugin classes could also be `extended` - a very well written plugin and good recommendation. +1

Answer (score 2):

Now in WP 4.7+ its easy ;)

According to 
https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/11/03/post-type-templates-in-4-7/ it is enough to create a page template stating which Post Types to associate with in the template header comment:

```
/*
Template Name: Full-width layout
Template Post Type: post, page, product
*/
```

The dropdown to select the template will appear automatically in the 'Post Attributes' metabox.

Comment: I just extended your answer to include an explanation on how to solve the issue. Just linking an external source won't help if one day the source disappears.